# Handle key events Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab

Tags: qt, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts, qml

I want to handle the two key events `Ctrl`+`Tab` and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Tab` in order to switch between tabs in my application ("forward" and "backward" respectively). However, this doesn't seem to work as expected.

This is my current code (minimal example):

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    focus: true

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if(event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
            if(event.key === Qt.Key_Tab) {
                if(event.modifiers & Qt.ShiftModifier)
                    console.log('backward')
                else
                    console.log('forward')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this piece of code with `qmlviewer` (Qt version 4.8.2)

Output when pressing `Ctrl`+`Tab`:

```
forward
forward
```

Output when pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Tab`:

> *none*

So I see two errors: The former key sequence is handled twice while the other one not at all.

- **EDIT:** The reason that the other one doesn't get handled at all is solved, see comments.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Note: I already use Qt Components for Desktop in my application, so it's OK if you know a solution requiring this module.

Comment: Ok I guess the problem is that Qt already maps `Shift`+`Tab` to `Qt::Key_Backtab` instead of `Qt::Key_Tab`. This solves the second problem, but not the problem that the key events are received *twice*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to accept the event, otherwise the event is propagated to the parents until it is accepted. The following code worked for me.

```
Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    focus: true

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if(event.modifiers && Qt.ControlModifier) {
            if(event.key === Qt.Key_Tab) {
                console.log('forward')
                event.accepted = true;
            }
            else if(event.key === Qt.Key_Backtab) {
                console.log('backward')
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This behavior lets parents handle events that the child could not, for things like hotkeys.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have an error in your code, `event.modifiers && Qt.ControlModifier` should be `event.modifiers == Qt.ControlModifier`. Otherwise, the second key events will work in combination with any `event.modifiers`